# Spring Data REST endpoint disappears (hibernate conflict)

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, spring-boot, spring-data-rest

I am trying to update my project to spring boot 2.0.5 version. And here is 
simple [github project](https://github.com/varren/spring-rest-api-disappear)

Essential part:

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "placement")
public class Placement {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    @Column(updatable = false)
    private Long id;

    private String name;

    @ManyToOne(fetch=FetchType.LAZY, cascade = CascadeType.REMOVE)
    private PlacementType type;

    //... getters and setters
}

@Entity
@Table(name = "placement_type")
public class PlacementType  {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    @Column(updatable = false)
    private Long id;

    private String name;
    //... getters and setters
}

@RepositoryRestResource(collectionResourceRel = "placement", path = "placement")
public interface PlacementRepository extends 
     PagingAndSortingRepository<Placement, Long> {}

@RepositoryRestResource(collectionResourceRel = "placementType", path = "placementType")
public interface PlacementTypeRepository extends 
     PagingAndSortingRepository<PlacementType, Long> {}
```

build.gradle

```
buildscript {
    ext {
        springBootVersion = '2.0.5.RELEASE'
    }

...

dependencies {
    compile("org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-data-jpa:${springBootVersion}")
    compile("org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-data-rest:${springBootVersion}")
    compile group: 'org.hibernate', name: 'hibernate-entitymanager', version: '5.3.6.Final'
    compile group: 'com.fasterxml.jackson.datatype', name: 'jackson-datatype-hibernate5', version: '2.9.0'
    compile 'com.h2database:h2:1.4.196'
}
```

**The problem:**

When i boot the app, both api endpoints work just fine:

```
GET http://localhost:8090/api/placement/ => 200 works fine
GET http://localhost:8090/api/placementType => 200 works fine
```

But after i visit PlacementType from Placement uri (`@ManyToOne`)  i can't access PlacementType endpoint any longer:

```
GET http://localhost:8090/api/placement/1/type => 200 works fine
GET http://localhost:8090/api/placementType => 404 (and default spring error screen)
```

No errors log, or maybe my logging level is incorrect, but i have no idea why request is redirected to the SimpleUrlHandlerMapping the second time.

```
 LOG from first GET http://localhost:8090/api/placementType => 200 
 02:38:56.076 [http-ni] DEBUG o.s.w.s.DispatcherServlet                - DispatcherServlet with name 'dispatcherServlet' processing GET request for [/api/placementType] 
 02:38:56.080 [http-ni] DEBUG s.w.s.m.m.a.RequestMappingHandlerMapping - Looking up handler method for path /api/placementType 
 02:38:56.088 [http-ni] DEBUG s.w.s.m.m.a.RequestMappingHandlerMapping - Did not find handler method for [/api/placementType] 
 02:38:56.114 [http-ni] DEBUG o.s.w.s.DispatcherServlet                - Last-Modified value for [/api/placementType] is: -1 
 Hibernate: select placementt0_.id as id1_1_, placementt0_.name as name2_1_ from placement_type placementt0_ limit ?
 02:38:56.559 [http-ni] DEBUG m.m.a.RequestResponseBodyMethodProcessor - Written [PagedResource { content: [Resource { content: com.varren.model.PlacementType@65e962bd, links: [<http://localhost:8090/api/placementType/1>;rel="self", <http://localhost:8090/api/placementType/1>;rel="placementType"] }], metadata: Metadata { number: 0, total pages: 1, total elements: 1, size: 20 }, links: [<http://localhost:8090/api/placementType{?page,size,sort}>;rel="self", <http://localhost:8090/api/profile/placementType>;rel="profile"] }] as "application/hal+json" using [org.springframework.data.rest.webmvc.config.RepositoryRestMvcConfiguration$ResourceSupportHttpMessageConverter@446c8c72] 
 02:38:56.562 [http-ni] DEBUG o.s.w.s.DispatcherServlet                - Null ModelAndView returned to DispatcherServlet with name 'dispatcherServlet': assuming HandlerAdapter completed request handling 
 02:38:56.563 [http-ni] DEBUG o.s.w.s.DispatcherServlet                - Successfully completed request 

                 GET http://localhost:8090/api/placement/1/type => 200 works fine
 LOG from second GET http://localhost:8090/api/placementType => 404 
 03:09:08.285 [http-ni] DEBUG o.s.w.s.DispatcherServlet                - DispatcherServlet with name 'dispatcherServlet' processing GET request for [/api/placementType] 
 03:09:08.286 [http-ni] DEBUG s.w.s.m.m.a.RequestMappingHandlerMapping - Looking up handler method for path /api/placementType 
 03:09:08.287 [http-ni] DEBUG s.w.s.m.m.a.RequestMappingHandlerMapping - Did not find handler method for [/api/placementType] 
 03:09:08.292 [http-ni] DEBUG o.s.w.s.h.SimpleUrlHandlerMapping        - Matching patterns for request [/api/placementType] are [/**] 
 03:09:08.292 [http-ni] DEBUG o.s.w.s.h.SimpleUrlHandlerMapping        - URI Template variables for request [/api/placementType] are {} 
 03:09:08.292 [http-ni] DEBUG o.s.w.s.h.SimpleUrlHandlerMapping        - Mapping [/api/placementType] to HandlerExecutionChain with handler [ResourceHttpRequestHandler [locations=[class path resource [META-INF/resources/], class path resource [resources/], class path resource [static/], class path resource [public/], ServletContext resource [/]], resolvers=[org.springframework.web.servlet.resource.PathResourceResolver@74eec640]]] and 1 interceptor 
 03:09:08.293 [http-ni] DEBUG o.s.w.s.DispatcherServlet                - Last-Modified value for [/api/placementType] is: -1 
 03:09:08.294 [http-ni] DEBUG o.s.w.s.DispatcherServlet                - Null ModelAndView returned to DispatcherServlet with name 'dispatcherServlet': assuming HandlerAdapter completed request handling 
 03:09:08.294 [http-ni] DEBUG o.s.w.s.DispatcherServlet                - Successfully completed request
```

One more thing. Most of the times i have this bug, but sometimes everything works just fine. I added second @Entity in github repo to show that sometimes one of 2 identical entities works and another doesn't, but maybe i'm missing something obvious

Comment: very strange. The only thing I would try now is to change the attribute name from `PlacementType type;` to `PlacementType placementType;`.

Comment: @Patrick yeah, tried this several times. Also tested several java versions. Switched to boot 2.0.6. After several days of debugging, i just feel so stupid for using the latest version of `hibernate-entitymanager` and never trying to remove the dependency.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like the problem was in deprecated `hibernate-entitymanager` or at least a version mismatch

```
compile group: 'org.hibernate', name: 'hibernate-entitymanager', version: '5.3.6.Final'
```

Took me several days to realize that it is no longer needed and that i should switch to `hibernate-core`. But switching to the latest hibernate-core also produced the same problem, so i had to completely remove the dependency and let `spring-boot-starter-data-jpa` use it's version (`5.2.17.Final` for boot `2.0.5.RELEASE`).

Debugged this with breakpoints in `RepositoryRestHandlerMapping.lookupHandlerMethod` and noticed strange `class com.varren.model.PlacementType$HibernateProxy` in RepositoryRestHandlerMapping cache.

[image]

The normal (working) version looks like this (without HibernateProxy): https://i.stack.imgur.com/1V0FU.png